# Fortran with Eclipse error: list missing 'path' of errors

Tags: linux, eclipse, ubuntu, fortran

I'm working with Fortran for academic purposes. It used to work OK in the past but after a OS upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 this issue started to happen.

When I compile a code with errors, they are listed in the Problems tab but in Project Explorer. The source files are not marked with red as before. This results in a painful search for the line in which the error is, instead of double clicking the error message and being automatically taken there.

I already rebooted and restarted Eclipse more than once, and tried a bunch of other things also. One important tip may be that it happens in Eclipse Mars 2 (the same one I used in Ubuntu 14.04) and the same behavior in Eclipse Neon (recently downloaded and installed).

Thanks in advance for any insight in this, not very serious, but yes very nagging, problem.

Comment: Do you use Photran or which layer of Fortran support do you use?

Comment: Photran indeed. In Eclipse Neon it comes already packaged with the Parallel Tools Platform (which is what is used for fortran applications)